# Switching custom views in a window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a .xib which had 1 window with `NSToolbar` and have multiple custom views all part of the same xib. When I click on the toolbar icon, it switches the view but doesn't show any buttons or other objects that I have on that view.

I know the views are getting switching because I have a different size for both views and the window is getting adjusted

Code which switches the view:

```
NSInteger tag = [sender tag];

NSView *view = [self viewForTag:tag];
NSView *previousView = [self viewForTag: currentViewTag];
currentViewTag = tag;
NSRect newFrame = [self newFrameForNewContentView:view];

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.1];

if ([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask)
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0];

[[[self.window contentView] animator] replaceSubview:previousView with:view];
[[self.window animator] setFrame:newFrame display:YES];

[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way, I'm not sure, but the way I switch views is like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.firstSubView = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.secondSubView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.customView addSubview: self.firstSubView.view];
    self.firstSubView.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;

    self.firstViewIsSelected = YES;
}

- (IBAction)viewSwitched:(id)sender {
    if (self.firstViewIsSelected) {
        [self.firstSubView.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.customView addSubview: self.secondSubView.view];
        self.secondSubView.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;
    }
    else{
        [self.secondSubView.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.customView addSubview: self.firstSubView.view];
        self.firstSubView.view.frame = self.customView.bounds;
    }
    self.firstViewIsSelected = !self.firstViewIsSelected;
}
```